# See how much memory was reserved with malloc() by a process on Linux

Tags: linux, process, memory

I know that if a process does a `malloc()` but doesn't actually write on this memory, Linux consider that this memory is free and can be used by other processes (overcommit).

Anyway, is there a way to know how much memory was `malloc()`ed by a given process? (even if not used)

This info exists on a system wide basis in `/proc/meminfo`, but I'd like to know for a specific process.

I dug in `/proc/<PID>/{smaps,stat,statm}` but I'm unsure that it displays this information.

Comment: Since you're running on Linux, `malloc_info()` might also be of interest:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_info.3.html  It doesn't really answer the question as it's only run from *within* a process, but if you do have control over the source code for your process(es) of interest, you might be able to make use of it.  There are also some hacks you can do with `LD_PRELOAD` to load a custom shared object into the address space when the process(es) start that could emit the information you need upon receipt of a signal, for example.  That might be a bit risky, though.

Comment: @Andrew you could also run the process in a debugger and call the function from the debugger...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calls to `malloc()` which cause the data segment size to change (*i.e.*, that don’t re-use previously allocated memory — so allocations which result in calls to `sbrk()` or `mmap()`) show up in `/proc/$PID/statm` and `/proc/$PID/stat`.

In `statm`, the first field shows the total program size, and the sixth field shows the number of pages of data; both of these reflect memory allocations (even when unused).

In `stat`, the field to look at is `vsize` (the 23rd field currently).

(See tables 1-3 and 1-4 in the [`proc` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html).)

Note that these show total memory use and total data segment sizes, so you can’t distinguish between memory that’s been `malloc()`ed and other memory usage.

You can see this in action with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  void *buf;
  puts("Waiting before allocating...");
  sleep(20);
  buf = malloc(10*1024*1024*1024L);
  puts("Sleeping after allocating...");
  sleep(20);
  free(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

(Excellent error handling as always.) Then

```
$ ./356532&
[1] 4239
Waiting before allocating...
$ cat /proc/4239/statm
1043 172 154 1 0 81 0
$ cat /proc/4239/stat | awk '{print $23}'
4272128
Sleeping after allocating...
$ cat /proc/4239/statm
2622484 172 154 1 0 2621522 0
$ cat /proc/4239/stat | awk '{print $23}'
10741694464
```

[Andrew Henle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/111943/andrew-henle) [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356532/see-how-much-memory-was-reserved-with-malloc-by-a-process-on-linux/356541#comment631985_356532) [`malloc_info(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_info.3.html), and you can actually use that on pretty much any process. Using the example program above, *without any debugging info* (just to show that it’s not necessary):

```
$ gdb ./356532
> break free
```

(this sets up a breakpoint at the call to `free` in the program — actually any call to `free`, but we’ll hit “ours” first; trying this with `malloc` won’t be as useful because the startup code uses `malloc`)

```
> run
```

When `gdb` hits a breakpoint, you can call `malloc_info` like this:

```
> call malloc_info(0, stdout)
```

This will dump the `malloc` information.